# Substitute file name in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I usually use this line `OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)` to substitute the .cpp extension of files in SOURCES to .o extension.
My project now has files with .c extension together with .cpp. How do I modify that line to make it substitute all .c and .cpp extensions to .o?

I would not prefer a two lines solution like below:

```
OBJECTS_TMP = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
OBJECTS = $(OBJECT_TMP:.c=.o)
```

I would like something like

```
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:(.cpp|.c)=.o)
```

or even

```
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.*=.o)
```

Is that possible and how?

Comment: A rough guess, but didn't test it: `$(SOURCES:.c=.o:.cpp=.o)`?

Comment: @NiklasR `$(SOURCES:.c=.o:.cpp=.o)` gives me `*** multiple target patterns.  Stop.` and `$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o:.c=.o)` gives `*** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it only with the shorthand.  You'll have to use the patsubst function:

```
OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SOURCES)))
```

Or you can use one of each:

```
OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SOURCES:.c=.o))
```

Or, you can do it like this:

```
OBJECTS = $(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(SOURCES)))
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot about nesting. This may work too `OBJECTS = $($(SOURCES:.cpp=.o):.c=.o)`. Thanks!

Comment: Nope.  In the shorthand method the item operated on must be a _variable name_.  It cannot be some random set of values.  It would have taken only seconds for you to try that and realize it doesn't work, before posting it, BTW.